# How to create three tables in page layout and need to get the table values from the sharepoint list?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath

I have  to create three tables in the page layout of SharePoint Designer 2010 and I need to get the table values from the list for the created table.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: OK, three tables in a page layout. So far so good. After that, your question is not clear. What exactly do the tables need to show? What is "the list for the created table"? Do you want to show list view web parts? Please provide more detail.

Comment: I have one sharepoint list(LISTA) which contains column. For ex: colum name is Teamname. The Team name contain multiples rows. I need to assign the teamname row values in the pagelayout table for the particular value. For ex: if the first table of the page layout contains Name field i need show the row values of team name in drop down of name field.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a List Filter Web Part for that. It does not even require InfoPath or SharePoint designer. You can configure which list field to use in the filter web part configuration.

Also, you would not want InfoPath to get anywhere NEAR page layouts anyway. - When you say "page layout", do you mean "Page Layout" as in Publishing pages' "Page Layouts"?

If you don't mean "Page Layout" in the publishing context, please update your question to explain the context you are referring to, e.g. a web part page or an InfoPath form.